# need some help writing shell script to add numbers

Tags: linux, bash, shell, arguments

basically writing a script that adds numbers supplied by user as arguments to the script. The number of arguments are unknown. Also have to check to make sure it is an int. The script should show result of numbers.

an example:

./addNumbers 10 5 10

sum is 25

Comment: #!/bin/bash

# check if more than 1 argument has been supplied by the user.

if[ $# -lt 1 ]
then

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go:-

```
sum=0
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Not enough arguments provided"
   echo "Correct uses : $0 23 22 25"
   echo "You can provide any number of argument"
   exit 1
fi
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    echo "$1"
    sum=$(($sum+$1))
    shift
done    
echo "sum is $sum"
```

Now you can try like:-

```
./addNumbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ....... 100
```

Here line 1 is a variable setting sum to 0. Line 2 is checking to make sure there is a greater number than 0. Then you echo the first argument second argument etc. Every iteration it will print next argument from the argument list.

Comment: This will only work if exactly 9 arguments are supplied.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, Thanks for your comment. I have modified my answer.

Comment: thanks! Just to clarify, line 1 is a variable setting sum to 0. line 2 is checking to make sure theres a greater number than 0. then you echo the first argument ? i just want to understand this better.

Comment: Yes true. I have added your comment in my answer so that other people also can understand this.

Comment: Thank you!! & another question.. say the user doesnt provide any arguments.  I want it to reply back with a message

Comment: example of something I worked on:then
echo "$0: usage: list of integers"
exit 1

Comment: Mels-MacBook-Pro:documents Mel$ ./addNumbers.sh 1 37 46
./addNumbers.sh: line 16: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./addNumbers.sh: line 17: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: nevermind I found the error! thank you!!!!

Comment: @Mel, is my answer helped?

Comment: It was extremely helpful, thanks so much. Line 4 just needs the closing quotation that was the error. thank you very much